# RANK() OVER Partition with resetting in dependence of another column

Tags: presto

I have in a table 2 different IDs and the timestamp, which I would like to rank. But the peculiarity is that I want to rank the S_ID until there is an entry at O_ID. Once there is an entry at O_ID, I want the next rank at S_ID to start at 1.

Here is an example:

```
select 
    S_ID,
    timestamp,
    O_ID,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY timestamp asc) AS RANK
from table
order by S_ID, timestamp;
```

| S_ID | Timestamp | O_ID | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-11-26 08:57:44.049 | NULL | 1 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-26 17:07:26.272 | NULL | 2 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-27 08:13:24.277 | NULL | 3 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-29 11:32:56.952 | 2287549 | 4 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-30 13:41:28.821 | NULL | 5 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-30 19:53:28.590 | NULL | 6 |
| 2e114e9f | 2022-02-05 09:50:54.104 | 2333002 | 7 |
| 2e114e9f | 2022-02-19 10:14:31.389 | NULL | 8 |

How can I now add another rank in dependence of an entry in the column O_ID?
So the outcome should be:

| S_ID | Timestamp | O_ID | Rank S_ID | Rank both |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-11-26 08:57:44.049 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-26 17:07:26.272 | NULL | 2 | 2 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-27 08:13:24.277 | NULL | 3 | 3 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-29 11:32:56.952 | 2287549 | 4 | 4 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-30 13:41:28.821 | NULL | 5 | 1 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-30 19:53:28.590 | NULL | 6 | 2 |
| 2e114e9f | 2022-02-05 09:50:54.104 | 2333002 | 7 | 3 |
| 2e114e9f | 2022-02-19 10:14:31.389 | NULL | 8 | 1 |

I am happy about any food for thought!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the gaps and islands approach can be helpful here - use `lag` to split data into groups (based on current and previous equality with some null handling) and then use group value as partition for the `rank()` function.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (S_ID, Timestamp, O_ID) AS (
    VALUES ('2e114e9f', timestamp '2021-11-26 08:57:44.049',    NULL),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2021-12-26 17:07:26.272',    NULL),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2021-12-27 08:13:24.277',    NULL),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2021-12-29 11:32:56.952',    2287549),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2021-12-30 13:41:28.821',    NULL),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2021-12-30 19:53:28.590',    NULL),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2022-02-05 09:50:54.104',    2333002),
    ('2e114e9f',    timestamp '2022-02-19 10:14:31.389',    NULL)
) 

--query
select S_ID,
    Timestamp,
    O_ID,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID, grp ORDER BY timestamp asc) AS RANK
from(
        select *,
            sum(if(prev is not null and (O_ID is null or O_ID != prev), 1, 0)) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY timestamp asc) as grp
        from (
                select *,
                    lag(O_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY S_ID ORDER BY timestamp asc) AS prev
                from dataset
            )
    )
```

Output:

| S_ID | Timestamp | O_ID | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-11-26 08:57:44.049 |  | 1 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-26 17:07:26.272 |  | 2 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-27 08:13:24.277 |  | 3 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-29 11:32:56.952 | 2287549 | 4 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-30 13:41:28.821 |  | 1 |
| 2e114e9f | 2021-12-30 19:53:28.590 |  | 2 |
| 2e114e9f | 2022-02-05 09:50:54.104 | 2333002 | 3 |
| 2e114e9f | 2022-02-19 10:14:31.389 |  | 1 |